# Are the following statements using pointer arithmetic involving out of bound aceess valid?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, undefined-behavior, pointer-arithmetic

```
char array[8] = "Raining";
```

I think all the below comments respective to the statements are true to my understanding.

```
char *p1 = array + 7;      --> points to '\0'

char *p2 = array + 8;      --> undefined behaviour

char *p3 = array + 9;      --> undefined behaviour

char *p4 = array + 10;     --> undefined behaviour
```

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your case,

```
  char *p1 = array + 7;
```

and

```
  char *p2 = array + 8;
```

are **valid**, because, you are legally allowed to point to

- any object inside the array length
- one past the last array element **until you dereference it**.

OTOH,

```
  char *p3 = array + 9;
```

and

```
  char *p4 = array + 10;
```

are undefined.

---

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.6, "Additive operators" (*emphasis mine*)

[*same in* `C99`, *chapter §6.5.6/p8, for anybody interested*]

> When an expression that has integer type is added to or subtracted from a pointer, the
>   result has the type of the pointer operand. **If the pointer operand points to an element of
>   an array object, and the array is large enough, the result points to an element offset from
>   the original element such that the difference of the subscripts of the resulting and original
>   array elements equals the integer expression.** In other words, if the expression `P` points to
>   the `i`-th element of an array object, the expressions `(P)+N` (equivalently, `N+(P)`) and
>   `(P)-N` (where `N` has the value `n`) point to, respectively, the `i+n`-th and `i−n`-th elements of
>   the array object, provided they exist. Moreover, if the expression `P` points to the last
>   element of an array object, the expression `(P)+1` points one past the last element of the
>   array object, and if the expression `Q` points one past the last element of an array object,
>   the expression `(Q)-1` points to the last element of the array object. **If both the pointer
>   operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last
>   element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the
>   behavior is undefined.** [...]

Comment: "you are legally allowed to point to one past the last array element until you dereference it" - really ? I've learned something new today... (I'd be interested to see the relevant section of the standard, if you or anyone else has it to hand?)

Comment: Upvoted.@SouravGhosh is correct here. Setting a pointer one past the last element of an array *is* allowed in C and C++. (It's how `end()` can be implemented in C++).

Comment: @Bathsheba: I can understand the C++ use case, but for C it's not clear why this would be allowed?

Comment: One past the address of a *scalar* is also allowed :-) Note that we're talking about *assignment* here and a read of the pointer, *not* a dereference.

Comment: @PaulR I have quoted the relevant part, is that ok?

Comment: @SouravGhosh: thanks for digging that out from the C11 standard - I wonder if it's always been specified (in C99 and before) or if this is a new thing ? Anyway, thanks - it's always good to learn something new... ;-)

Comment: How to dereference it ?

Comment: @stackuser dereference what?

Comment: how can we dereference the last element ?

Comment: @stackuser not very sure what you're trying to ask here, using the dereference operator (`*`, or array indexing `[]`)....right?

Comment: @PaulR sir, just confimed, same in C99, please check the edit. :)

Comment: Is array + 1000 valid until we derefernce it ?

Comment: @stackuser nopes, no. __one past the last array__ and that's it. period.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: cool - thanks for the additional reference to the C99 standard. Now I'm curious as to whether pointing to *one element before the first element* might also be valid, for the same reason, but for the use case of loops that iterate in the reverse direction ?

Comment: @PaulR: No it ain't. This explains the reason why reverse iterators in C++ are so maddeningly asymmetrical. (Forward iterator = reversiterator.base() - 1).

Comment: @PaulR Sir, as I read the quote, the valid scenarios are _"If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object,"_ , rest are UB. So, I believe, even thought the `-1` scenario is not mentioned explicitly, implicitly, it's UB, as the _exception_ for `last+1` is mentioned explicitly.

Comment: The reason why you are allowed to address one past the end of the array is because of iterations. It allows you to do things like `for(int* start = &array[0], int* end = &array[size]; start != end; start++) {...}` which is very similar to C++ iterators.

Comment: @Lundin: right, but what about reverse iteration - why not apply the same rule there, and allow a pointer to point at `a[-1]` ?

Comment: @PaulR Probably because it is far less common. As soon as you start digging into the rationale about a certain feature in C, you usually come to the conclusion that there is no sound rationale. It's a hopelessly irrational and inconsistent language.

Comment: @SouravGhosh, accessing an element one past the array element won't throw array out of bounds exception ?

Comment: @stackuser as long as you're not accessing the memory, it should be fine, the expression involving or resulting a pointer one past the last object should be fine.

Comment: @stackuser and for C, there's no "exception", accessing out of bound memory invokes UB, segmentation fault is one of the side effects.

Comment: @SouravGhosh, okay we are just setting a pointer to that position as we can set a pointer to any address, but we cant access that , it is a undefined behaviour or segmentation fault, so if i try to access one past the end of an array , then it is UB . Am i right now ?

Comment: @PaulR: Reverse iterations are handled by initializing a pointer with the "just-past" address and then decrementing it *before* each access.

Comment: @supercat: interesting - this rings bells regarding the PDP-8 instruction set - post-increment and pre-decrement addressing modes.

Comment: @PaulR: I think it's helpful to think of pointers as identifying the mile markers *between* the spaces occupied by data objects.  A range of n objects starting at p thus includes the space between mile marker at p to the mile marker at p+n.  By convention, *p identifies one object's worth of space between p and p+1.

Answer (score 5):

`array` has 8 elements in it due to the NULL-terminator.

`char *p1 = array + 7;` is well-defined.

`char *p2 = array + 8;` is actually **defined**. You're allowed to set a pointer to one-past the array. (Just don't *dereference* it.)

The other two are **undefined**. You're not allowed to set a pointer beyond one-past the array.

Comment: "You're allowed to set a pointer to one-past the array". Explain this please?

Comment: @stackuser In case you're interested, I've added the quote to my version, anyway. :)

Comment: @stackuser Setting a pointer to one element past the end of the array is explicitly allowed so that the pointer value can be used as an exclusive endpoint.  That is, it allows things like: `char* end = array + 8; for (char* p = array; p < end; p++) { /* Do something with *p */ }`

Comment: @Bathsheba, accessing an element one past the array element won't throw array out of bounds exception ?

Comment: If, by accessing, you mean *defererencing*, then the behaviour is undefined.

Answer (score 4):

The first line points to a legal element inside the array and the second line is valid until dereferenced. The rest of your post is right.

```
char *p1 = array + 7;   \\-->points to '\0', within array

char *p2 = array + 8;   \\-->defined behaviour until dereferenced
```

The reason the *past-the-end* addressing is allowed is to make it easy to write a loop to go over an entire array, e.g., while (`*d++ = *s++);`.

[image]

The boundary markers for arrays describe a half-open range, starting with (and including) the first element, and ending with (but not including) the last element: `[beginning,end)`.

Comment: I find it easiest to think of pointers as identifying the boundaries *between* memory locations; *p means the object between the boundaries identified by p and p+1, which coincides with how your picture is drawn.  When described in such terms, a pointer is valid if it identifies the start of any data object or the end of any data object.

Comment: @supercat I agree with you completely, this is great intuitive approach.

Comment: I first encountered such descriptions in Inside Macintosh, in its description of Quickdraw graphics and the use of coordinates to identify spaces between pixels, but it works nicely with pointers as well.  If "foo" is an array of ten items, then "foo+0" identifies ten items after it, "foo+1" identifies one item before it and nine items after it; "foo+2" identifies two before and eight after, up to "foo+10" which identifies 10 before and none after.